# Is this the correct way to form a closure in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, closures

`iD` is an object that changes on every iteration in a loop. Also in this loop I run the following:

```
$("td.item_holder > div").append(dynamo.shop.box.ini(item_info,(function(data){
    return function(){
        console.log(data);
    }
})(iD)));
```

I'm hoping that this forms a closure. My only query is, the function it calls `dynamo.shop.box.ini` uses `.bind` (jQuery) as such:

```
ini : function(data,callback){
....
            var right = $('<div>').addClass("dynamo_right").html('bye').bind('click',callback);
....
    return container;
},
```

Do I need to use another anonymous function on the `.bind` call to keep the closure?

Comment: There are plenty of question on StackOverflow about closures already. Just search it: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `ini` is a function per se, and therefore has its own scope. So, the arguments passed to `ini` on each call won't change, and another closure is not necessary.